# How to do a verify automatic checkbox when hit the api?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, api

How to do a verify automatic checkbox when hit the api?

i already create one table and also model, respository, services and also mapping. So my question is how to implement a verify automatic checkbox when hit the api in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

after successful api calling it will return some value or boolean data. so use that data as a condition to check the checkbox. would you please share the api calling function of javascript and the controller code? so that I can understand your scenario.

Comment: alright. im newbie, can i share my whole controller?

Comment: yes please and also javascript function.

Comment: unlucky i cant share my whole controller due maximum content T.T

Comment: just share the js function and the last part of your controller.